# Conditional clothing product options based on Size and Color

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations, conditional-attribute

I have a Woocommerce website in which we sell printed t-shirts, hoodies and sweatshirts. We have two product attributes; Size and Color. Currently, we're using the built-in attributes options like this (Our site is in Persian so I used a translator for you, it looks different because of that but we're using the defaults of Woocommerce):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqMgt.jpg

Now the problem is that if we want to make a specific size of a specific t-shirt unavailable, we have to either change the variations in products one by one (It's impossible because we have thousands of products with at least 70 variations) or use a plugin to bulk select and edit variations which we do. But it's still very slow and inefficient. As we add more products, it gets harder and slower to change a variation's status.

So what we need is a way to add global conditional logic that let us define which size of which color is available for t-shirts at any given time without needing to change anything inside the product editor. I've tried plugins like [Yith Woocommerce Product Add-ons](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-add-ons/) but they don't solve our problem. As you can see from the image, they let you set a single conditional logic for a whole field, they don't provide a solution for adding conditional logic to each option in a field.
[Yith Product Add-ons limitation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDvvG.jpg)

Can you help me find a solution to this problem? In short, I need a plugin or solution that lets me set conditional logic for my attributes from the admin panel for t-shirt size and color without needing to set them in product pages.